# Tensor("args_0:0", shape=(28, 28, 1), dtype=float32)

Tags: tensorflow, python-3.6, tensorflow-serving

I was trying to execute the code below in Google Colab for learning purposes.I got this message when i executed the following code.

Tensor("args_0:0", shape=(28, 28, 1), dtype=float32)

```
def normalize(images, labels):
  print(images)

  images = tf.cast(images, tf.float32)
  print(images)

  images /= 255
  print(images)


  return images, labels
```

I am trying to understand what this message means but I am not able ti understand it. Tried searching in web , but couldn't find much resources. Can anyone say what this statements mean?

Comment: It's the result of `print(images)`. `images` is a `Tensor` object, with name `"args_0:0"`, of shape `(28,28,1)` and of type float.

Comment: Thanks.I also got the this statement as well. Tensor("truediv:0", shape=(28, 28, 1), dtype=float32) Here does "truediv:0" also refers the name of the tensor ?

Comment: @KulothunganSenthil truediv (true division) is the name of the division operation performed at ```images /= 255```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This output means that your images are a tensor of shape `(28,28,1)` and type `float32` the 1 in `(28,28,1)` is a single byte for `gray-scale` meaning you have gray-scale images (basing on your code)