# "args_0:0" when printing Tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, image-rotation, data-augmentation

I have an augmentation function that is being mapped into a generator; however, for some reason, the `tfa.image.rotate` function is causing an error.

```
def customGenerator(input_file_paths, dims, data_type):
    for i, file_path in enumerate(input_file_paths):
        if data_type.decode("utf-8") in ["png" or "tif"]:
            img = plt.imread((file_path.decode("utf-8")))
        elif data_type.decode("utf-8") == "npy":
            img = np.load(file_path.decode("utf-8"))
        x = resize(img[:,:,:3], dims)           
        yield x, x

def augment(image,label) :
    print('image', image)
    print('shape', image.shape)
    print('type', type(image))

    #angle = random.uniform(0, tf.constant(np.pi))
    image = tfa.image.rotate(image, tf.constant(np.pi)


train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(generator=customGenerator, 
                                                 output_types=(np.float32, np.float32), 
                                                 output_shapes=(dims, dims), 
                                                 args=[X_train_paths, dims, "png"])

train_dataset = train_dataset.map(augment, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
```

I looked at the implementation of `tfa.image.rotate` other people had used, and theirs was working fine. I tried printing the `image` variable in the augment function. And this resulted:

```
print('image', image) # these lines is in the augment function, result below
print('type', type(image))
```

```
image Tensor("args_0:0", shape=(256, 256, 3), dtype=float32)
type <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'>
```

In contrast, when I go to other user's implementations and print their image, which is not mapped into a dataset. Their `print(image)` and `print(type(image))` prints out this:

```
image tf.Tensor(
[[[1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1.]
  ...
  [1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1.]]

 ...

 [[1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1.]
  ...
  [1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1.]]], shape=(256, 256, 3), dtype=float32)

type <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor'>
```

I expected this to be printing when I printed `image` in the  `augment` function. So I am unsure what is going one. So a couple of questions.
Also, `tf.executing_eagerly()` results in `True`

What exactly does `"args_0:0"` mean?

Should the image in the `augment` function be of type `<class  'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor'>` instead of a normal tensor?

Is there some way I can make `"args_0:0"` into the format I expected to have where it prints the array of numbers? Cause I believe that this will fix the rotation function

Finally, if not, is there a better way to augment the image with a random rotation?

Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: Can you share the result of `tf.executing_eagerly()`?

Comment: The result of tf.executing_eagerly() is true

Comment: What is dims arguments and the resize function used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`args_0:0` is tensor. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58391052/tensorargs-00-shape-28-28-1-dtype-float32)

I made some changes to your code in order to make it work.

Code:

```
import tensorflow_addons as tfa
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np


def customGenerator(input_file_paths, dims, data_type):
    for i, file_path in enumerate(input_file_paths):
        image = tf.io.read_file(file_path)
        image = tf.image.decode_png(image, channels = 3)
        image = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(image, tf.float32)
        image = tf.image.resize(image, [dims[0],dims[1]])
        yield image, image

def augment(image,label) :
    img = tfa.image.rotate(image, tf.constant(np.pi/8))   
    return (img, label)

X_train_paths = [os.path.join('data','img',name) for name in os.listdir('data/img')]
dims = (256,256,3)

train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(generator=customGenerator, 
                                                 output_types=(tf.float32, tf.float32), 
                                                 output_shapes=(dims, dims), 
                                                 args=[X_train_paths, dims, "png"])

train_dataset = train_dataset.map(augment)
```

Iterating over the dataset:

```
for images in train_dataset:
    rotatedimg, normalimg= images[0],images[1]
    break
```

Output:

```
plt.imshow(rotatedimg)
```

[image]

```
plt.imshow(normalimg)
```

[image]

Things to remember:

1. The map function is not executed eagerly.
2. Always use TensorFlow function inside your generator function and map function because TensorFlow executes these functions as a part of the graph in order to speed up its execution. See [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/27811)
3. If you use other functions TensorFlow might not be able to convert these operations into graphs which will result in an error.

Comment: Can you please accept and upvote the answer if it worked.